# Class inheritance obsecure

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I was going through a old code written by someone i encountered one class defined as

```
class SomenameofClass::Someanothername of the class
{

//some code goes here 
};
```

what does it mean ?
does it signifies private inheritance ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571355/why-would-one-use-nested-classes-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of a nested class which was declared elsewhere like this:

```
class SomenameofClass
{
  class Someanothername;
};
```

Usually this is done when the nested class is only used in the implementation of the outer class, so its definition doesn't need to be exposed in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes are considered to be within the scope of the enclosing class and are available for use within that scope. To refer to a nested class from a scope other than its immediate enclosing scope, you must use a fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

Its nested class, these are used to avoid name conflicts among different scopes. If a class is used by only one class, nest it, it will avoid naming conflicts and you will be notified if there is any conflict by intellisense