# C++: defining a struct inside another struct?

Tags: c++, struct

so I've been playing around with C++. I was trying to figure out if it's possible to define a structure in the definition of another structure. And here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    struct structure1{
        int integer1;
        struct structure2{
            int integer2;
        }struct2;
    }struct1;
    structure1 *s1 = &struct1;
    s1->integer1 = 50;
    cout<<"STRUCTURE ONE'S INTEGER: "<<s1->integer1<<endl;
    cout<<"STRUCTURE ONE'S STRUCTURE2.integer2: "<<s1->struct2.integer2;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ ./a.out
STRUCTURE ONE'S INTEGER: 50
STRUCTURE ONE'S STRUCTURE2.integer2: 0
```

From what I saw in the output it had seemed to be working. But I just don't understand why or how it worked. Is it good practice? Is there any application to this?

Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong besides the lack of an initialization of `integer2`.

Comment: @E_net4 I did, but what I typed seemed to be cutoff for some reason, I've put the rest back in.

Comment: Nevertheless, your question makes it look like you haven't read about aggregate types in C++ and the fact that you can nest them.

Comment: I can't cast it but this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4571355/560648

Comment: It works because it is valid syntax. I have seen this used before. Normally declaring a enum or another struct that will only ever be used by that class or struct internally.

Answer (score 0):

> But I just don't understand why or how it worked.

Why wouldn't it work? It's perfectly legal C++.

> Is it good practice?

Depends on how it's used.

> Is there any application to this?

Definitely. For example when you only need `structure2` inside `structure1` and nowhere else. It's good to make its scope as small as possible.

For more information: [Why would one use nested classes in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4571355/3425536)