# Convert C# class to C++ in implementing graph nodes in C++

Tags: c#, c++, class

```
private class Node
 {
    public int Value;
    public Node[] ChildNodes;
    public bool Selected;
 }
```

The class Node contains an array of Nodes.

Comment: You only want that class written in C++ instead of C#?

Comment: Yeah...I don't want structure but class.

Comment: Don't even bother - this is exactly the kind of job where C++ and C# are so dissimilar, you're better off starting from scratch. Which means learning C++ :P

Comment: I know c++ but what I want is a class having an array of itself within it and I am not able to implement it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My C++ is very rusty. Before we tackle the coding there are some things you need to know.

Classes can not directly have access modifiers like `public`, `protected`, `private` or  in C++. Meaning we are getting a problem already at `private class Node`.

This you can go around by using an [`Nested Class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571355/why-would-one-use-nested-classes-in-c)

This brings (psuedo) code to this:

```
class Outer 
{
    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
        }
};
```

We then have to add the the fields, usually (at least used to) in C++ you are using a prefix for variable names, much like capitalizing fields in C#.

```
int     mValue;
Node*   mNodes;
bool    mSelected;
```

Which brings us to the final Class:

**outer.h**

```
#ifndef OUTER_H
#define OUTER_H

class Outer 
{
    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                int     mValue;
                Node*   mNodes;
                bool    mSelected;
        }
};

#endif
```

More of the "Include guard" can be read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). In some enviroment you can use `#pragma once` instead of the guards.

I hope this gets you started. This code has not been tested.

*This is a bit of XYZ problem, we don't know for what reason you want to write it in C++ instead of C#. Working with C++ can be a hassle. I also (in both cases) recommend to work with a List in C# a Vector in C++ instead of an Array.*

Comment: g++ gives error near ) " expected unqualified-id before ) " in Node

Comment: Remove the parentheses, they are not supposed to be there. My IDE added them for me. Also,please read the post and do not copy-paste it, you would've found the error yourself had you been following the links. I am far from a C++ expert.

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives error near Node[ ].  " expected unqualified-id before [ " I actually need to implement some graph algorithm in c++. I know c# is hassle free but then I am told to perform the program in c++ itself

Comment: `Node    mNodes[];` should be like that in C++. Again. Every error takes a couple of seconds to find if you try.

Comment: I tried that too previously with every possible combination but it still gives error "mNodes has incompatible type"

Comment: this works thanks, so I will dynamically allocate memory for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, private classes in C# must be contained within an outer type, so we can assume that this type is already nested (i.e., neither C# nor C++ allows a private class at the namespace level). Next, it's much easier to use std::vector instead of actual arrays:

```
#include <vector>

//class Outer { - your existing outer class
    class Node
    {
    public:
        int Value = 0;
        std::vector<Node*> ChildNodes;
        bool Selected = false;
    };
//}; - end of your existing outer class
```