# Whats the meaning of "Class1::Class2" in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I'm analysing a code and encountered the following structure. Whats the relation of Class1 and Class2? (the project has been developed on Qt framework).

Simpilified Code:

```
class Class1
{
    ...

private:
    class Class2
}

class Class1::Class2: public BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Class2` is a member of `Class1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571355/why-would-one-use-nested-classes-in-c). It's basically a class declaration in another class declaration, quite similar to declaring a class inside a namespace.

If you make it private, only the outer class can access it. It's useful for organizing your implementation details without other classes or namespaces "seeing" it.

Answer (score 2):

`Class2` is a private nested class inside `Class1`, One may wonder why this is used at all, there are many reasons amongst which I see the best to be the PImpl idiom.

[PIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), hides the implementation details, so you add all your implementation under `Class::Class2`, then the `public` interface to your `Class` is very thin, in other words you expose very less.