# Undefined behavior during destrction?

Tags: c++, destruction

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{ virtual void foo(){ } };

struct B : A { virtual void foo(){ } };

A *a = new B;


int main()
{
    delete a; //UB?
}
```

I deliberately didn't define a virtual destructor. The compiler printed a message about causing UB, is it true?

Comment: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403883/derived-class-with-non-virtual-destructor)

Comment: Why would the compiler lie to you???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally you have UB if you delete through a pointer to T, which is not the most derived type, and T doesn't have a virtual destructor.

In practice you can get away with it if you don't have any data mambers, but it's still very ungood and unnecessary practice.

Note: when you use a `shared_ptr` it creates a deleter function at the point of initialization, and that deleter function can remember the original type, which, if that type is the most derived type, ensures well-defined deletion. E.g. in your case `shared_ptr<A> p( new B );` would be OK.

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's good practice to rely on this capability of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Nice, distinction about the `shared_ptr` I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: To me, this behavior of `std::shared_ptr` is more of a side-effect rather than by intention.

Comment: @Lingxi: The single pointer argument constructor is templated only in order to support this functionality. Without giving this support, it would not need to be templated. So it's very much by design: there is a templating just for this purpose.