# Inheritance type forcing

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible to make inheritance forced to be public, private or protected?

Ie:

```
class block: public shape{ // Only way to inherit from shape
};

// class block: private shape{}; // throws an error
```

To make things more clear:

- this will not cause an error in its current state
- **What I want to achieve** is to enforce the constraint where any class that derives from `shape` be public. eg. If a class tries to privately inherit from `shape` that should trigger a compile error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184133/prevent-class-inheritance-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is generally no way that a base can dictate the interfaces of its derived classes. Such constraint doesn't seem to solve any problem, and "forced publicity" could easily be worked around by restricting access to the derived class.

For example, `Square` here provides a public interface to `Shape`, but nobody can access `Square` anyway due to access protection.

```
class SquaresAreAllMine {
private:
    class Square : public Shape {};
};
```

(Declaring signatures of virtual functions is an exception, as there is no way for a derived class to revert to non-virtual status. This is not really intended to be restrictive, though.)

Comment: I'll accept your answer and take your word, but could you explain how to "restrict access" to derived classes?

Comment: @Lemony Added an example of what I meant.