# Is there some way to detect if a class is being incorrectly deleted using non-virtual base destructor?

Tags: c++

The very well known scenario:

```
#include <memory>

class A{};
class B : public A {};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>();
    // bam, when a gets deleted, we have undefined behavior.
    return 0; 
}
```

Moreover, not even Valgrind can catch such an error, provided that the size of `A` and `B` are the same.

Is there some tool that could catch such errors at least for a debug build, or some idiom which would detect such errors for a specified class?

Comment: Do you want to have the functionality? Otherwise, you can just disable inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12319547/1287254

Comment: Great! That solves the practical problem I am solving right now, but I would like to know the general case, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Depends, but [std::has_virtual_destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_virtual_destructor) might be part of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For gcc you can specify:

```
-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wsystem-headers
```

to see `delete-non-virtual-dtor` warning generated `by std::default_delete`, it will look as follows:

> /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:2: warning: deleting object of polymorphic class type 'B' which has non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
>     delete __ptr;

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccc60cb14f09c6d9)

btw. your sample classes lack at least one virtual function in base class.

[edit]

to turn it into error use:

```
 -Werror=delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wsystem-headers
```

Comment: I don't think you need a virtual destructor when you're using `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 you're thinking of shared_ptr, which type-erases the deleter. Unique_ptr needs a virtual destructor on the base class.

Comment: This only happens if you add a virtual function, but then you can catch the problem much earlier with -Weffc++.

Comment: adding virtual function should not be required, I agree. I tried this with `-Weffc++` but I dont see it catches non-virtual base destructor problem for this sample code, or I dont know how to use it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17c5c165298c7b5a

Comment: -Weffc++ warns when you define a class with a virtual function but non-virtual dtor.

Answer (score 1):

It is my strong opinion that one should strictly separate "value-based" classes and "OO-based" classes (for lack of better term).

Value-based classes should have no public bases, and should normally support copy semantics (unless specially designed to disable copying). Objects of such classes have no identities apart from their values. They are interchangeable with their copies.

OO-based classes should have virtual destructors, and should never have copying members publicly accessible. Objects of such classes should only be copied via a virtual `clone` method. Such objects have identities separate from their values.

There should be no class with a public base that has a non-virtual destructor or a public copy/move ctor or a public copy/move assignment operator (in the base).

If you maintain this separation, you will have no accidents with object slicing or deletion through a non-polymorphic base pointer.

Unfortunately there are no tools (that I know of) that help maintain this separation. So you need to exercise due diligence while inheriting. It's really simple. Does it have a virtual dtor *and* inaccessible/deleted copy ctor and copy assignment? You can inherit publicly. No? Avoid potential mess, use composition or private inheritance.

A good class designed for inheritance would have its copying members protected in order to facilitate cloning in descendant classes.

Unfortunately, with third-party classes you don't have a choice, as authors usually leave copying members public, so there's still risk of object slicing. But you will have no risk of improper deletion through a base pointer.

TL;DR no tools, only programmer's due diligence.